# deleted ubuntu touch from galaxy nexus, now there is no os, how can i sideload os from windows

Tags: ubuntu-touch, data-recovery, galaxy-nexus

I installed Ubuntu touch on my galaxy nexus. I wanted to put the most recent build on it so I deleted Ubuntu and now I don't have an os. Windows sees my phone in device manager but I cannot access the internal storage to put the image on the sd card to re deploy.

help

Answer (score 1):

Have you read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Restoring_Android ?

The instructions would still apply for the exception of step 5 which mentions

```
adb reboot-bootloader
```

Where instead you would want to power cycle the device by pressing `Power`, `Volume Up` and `Volume Down` to reach the bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to recovery? or download mode?
You might want to take a look at [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2065470) thread over on XDA...
Wish I could comment as this isn't much of an answer...